# Text in TikZ with perspective (not just slant)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to display text in Ti*k*Z that is perspectively distorted, like so:

[image]

<sup>(checkered pattern added for illustration only)</sup>

There are many similar solutions on TeX.SE ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62038/text-placed-in-pespective-on-3d-object), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84621/adjusting-font-size-for-fake-perspective), or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447114/aligning-a-text-in-3d-diagram/447201#447201)), but all of the ones I found are faking perspective merely by using slant and tilt.

The solution should transform the text to:

1. have a horizontal vanishing point to which all usually horizontally parallel lines are noticeably converging
2. have a vertical vanishing point to which all usually vertically parallel lines are converging or keep them strictly parallel (like in my example above)

- Bonus if your solution allows the user to explicitly define the vanishing point.

You may use this as a starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,align=left] at (0,0) {some text\\maybe with line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319222/121799 and the other answers to the corresponding question as well as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447120/121799. And the last of your references, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447114/aligning-a-text-in-3d-diagram/447201#447201, doesn't fake perspectives at all. Rather it allows you to set the vanishing point(s).

Comment: So in short: With text, we can only get slant/tilt, with images more is possible but only at significant costs.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319222/121799 does it to texts, doesn't it? A very crazy thing you can do is to draw the letters with Ti*k*Z and then they can get transformed with Max great routines, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447114/aligning-a-text-in-3d-diagram/447201#447201. Some letters that can be transformed can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475168/121799 but they are not really good quality. (I used them to transform text nonlinearly on surfaces of spheres.

Comment: It's basically treating the text as as image and slicing it up, no? so there is nothing copy-and-pasteable/searchable afterwards. So it seems I have to give up on that idea.

Comment: I would use asymptote for that. The problem is that you need, AFAIK, the outlines of glyphs to be able to transform them. Asymptote knows how to get them, Ti*k*Z doesn't. I do not know how asymptote does it.[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21594/121799) is some way to get something of that sort with Ti*k*Z. And yes, by itself the text won't be searchable (but I guess you could make it searchable).

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll look at it

Comment: @sheß Any news? I am still waiting an answer! A very good question.

Comment: No news, I more or less accepted @marmot 's comment that this is beyond Ti*k*Z capabilities :(

Comment: @JouleV These are, in a way, two questions: 1. How can I get the outlines of glyphs in Ti*k*Z. 2. How can I do the perspective projection. 2. is a solved problem, and there will be a library soon. So the main task is 1. This has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21548/121799). What I don't know is whether or not there is a more automatic solution that does not require external programs. If you are willing to use external programs, then you may just use asymptote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This approach divides the word into small triangles
and apply slant and tilt to each triangle.
This works for projections as well as general nonlinear transformations.

It has appeared before

- [Seasonal Challenge (Contributions from TeXing Dead Welcome)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336768/seasonal-challenge-contributions-from-texing-dead-welcome/336821#336821)
- [Draw Text in different shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313880/draw-text-in-different-shapes/332173#332173)
- [Geometric inversion of an image (png, jpg, bmp)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374338/geometric-inversion-of-an-image-png-jpg-bmp/376128#376128)

---

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{188pt}{0}\bfseries

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fxx}{2}{\pgfmathparse{fx(#1+1,#2)-fx(#1,#2)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fxy}{2}{\pgfmathparse{fy(#1+1,#2)-fy(#1,#2)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fyx}{2}{\pgfmathparse{fx(#1,#2+1)-fx(#1,#2)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fyy}{2}{\pgfmathparse{fy(#1,#2+1)-fy(#1,#2)}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gx}{2}{\pgfmathparse{3*#1-20}}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gy}{2}{\pgfmathparse{3.1622*#2}}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gz}{2}{\pgfmathparse{#1+10}}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{fx}{2}{\pgfmathparse{gx(#1,#2)*6/gz(#1,#2)}}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{fy}{2}{\pgfmathparse{gy(#1,#2)*6/gz(#1,#2)}}
    \clip(-15,-9)rectangle(15,10);
    \foreach\i in{0,...,40}{
        \foreach\j in{-3,...,3}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\aa{fxx(\i,\j)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\ab{fxy(\i,\j)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\ba{fyx(\i,\j)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{fyy(\i,\j)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\xx{fx (\i,\j)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\yy{fy (\i,\j)}
            \pgflowlevelobj{
                \pgfsettransformentries{\aa}{\ab}{\ba}{\bb}{\xx cm}{\yy cm}
            }{
                \clip(1,0)--(0,0)--(0,1)--cycle;
                \draw(1,0)--(0,0)--(0,1)--cycle;
                \tikzset{shift={(-\i,-\j)}}
                \path(20,.5)node{WORDART};
            }
            \pgfmathsetmacro\aa{fxx(\i  ,\j+1)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\ab{fxy(\i  ,\j+1)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\ba{fyx(\i+1,\j  )}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{fyy(\i+1,\j  )}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\xx{fx (\i+1,\j+1)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\yy{fy (\i+1,\j+1)}
            \pgflowlevelobj{
                \pgfsettransformentries{\aa}{\ab}{\ba}{\bb}{\xx cm}{\yy cm}
            }{
                \clip(0,0)--(-1,0)--(0,-1)--cycle;
                \draw(0,0)--(-1,0)--(0,-1)--cycle;
                \tikzset{shift={(-\i-1,-\j-1)}}
                \path(20,.5)node{WORDART};
            }
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot With `\usepackage{lmodern}` in the preamble, I obtain the same output as the screenshot with `pdflatex`, and the warning `Font shape \`OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <188> not available (Font) size <24.88> substituted on input line 3.` is gone (with the warning, the text in the output is tiny.) Tested with this configuration : *This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)*.

Comment: @marmot Sorry I did not notice that I set the compiler to XeLaTeX. But yeah as quark67 said this is a font issue. The tikz part is portable.

Comment: @JouleV Do you use `pdflatex` ? If yes, I obtain a very same output as you, but with  a "gray" grid like Symbol1, it's a antialiasing effect in my pdf viewer (perhap's your PDF viewer is different with antialiasing?). But as I wrote earlier, if you add `\usepackage{lmodern}` in the preamble, you probably give the same output as Symbol1.